# Accessing WCF Rest Service (Method='POST') from android device

Tags: android, wcf, rest, http-post

I have a wcf rest service hosted on deployment server and i am trying to call it from an android device. I have tried almost all things on internet but it is still not working, it keeps giving me an error 'Endpoint not found'. Following is my code snippet

Android code:

```
            string url = "http://productionservertmp.com/Service1.svc/PostServiceRequest";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);    

            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("reqobj", "Greetings from Android client");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( jobj.toString() );
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            response = client.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = null;
            JSONArray jsonResponse = null;
            try {
                  data = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //Here's where i find out about response (endpoint not found)
                  jsonResponse = new JSONArray(data);
             } catch (Exception e) {}


            //Signature of my function in interface:
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "PostServiceRequest", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
            string PostServiceRequest(string reqobj);

           //Method in Implementation class
           public string PostServiceRequest(string reqobj)
           {
               return "Response: "+reqobj;
           }

           //And in web.config on deployment server, I've following
           <services>
           <service name="Service1">
           <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" bindingConfiguration="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService1">
           </endpoint>
           </service>
           </services>
```

I have another function in same service with Method = "GET" and it's been called successfully. Problem lies somewhere with POST method. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

there is something wrong with your service url:

http://productionservertmp.com/Service1.svc/PostServiceRequest

It is not accessible on browser. Make sure it works.

Point 2:
Configure service properly using [WebInvoke], because you have a service parameter to send.

[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PostServiceRequest/{reqobj}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]

Try these changes.